# How to use CASE as a switch

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function with 4 parameters, which returns an int.
I want to return a results based od function parameter @Type.

I've tried:

```
SELECT @Result =

        CASE @Type

        WHEN 'Country' THEN
            BEGIN
                SELECT
                    IIF(COUNT(spc.DateID) = 0, 0, 1)
                FROM
                    dim.SalesPlanCountry spc
                    JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON spc.DateID = cal.DateID
                WHERE
                    cal.CalendarYear    = @Year
                    AND cal.MonthOfYear = @Month
                    AND spc.CountryID   = @CountryID
            END

        WHEN 'Region' THEN
           BEGIN        
              ...

END
```

Comment: Just use `if` and four different queries.

Comment: `CASE` is an expression; it's can't be used to define query logic for what statements to be run. Use `IF` and `ELSE IF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `IF` blocks instead:

```
IF @Type = 'Country'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table1
END

IF @Type = 'Bob'
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table2
END
```